# Why is Firebase Installations request returning a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, http-status-code-404, firebase-remote-config

Wondering if anyone has run into Firebase Installations getting 404 repose.
As i understand it firebase installations, is called by firebase after the base library is initialized.

It is hitting this url: [https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"projectKey"/installations/"api](https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%22projectKey%22/installations/%22api) key"/authTokens:generate.

we get back this console error:
FirebaseError: Installations: Generate Auth Token request failed with error "404 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found."

This is only happening in our prod environment i haven't been able to reproduce it locally.

So wondering if anyone else ran into this.

The base firebase library is being initialized from a react js app.

We define it by:

```
const registerFirebaseApp = (config?: FirebaseOptions): FirebaseApp | undefined => {
  if (!config || isUnitTestMode) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return initializeApp(config, config.appId);
};

export const webFirebaseApp = registerFirebaseApp(
  validateFirebaseConfig({
    apiKey: StaticConfig.firebaseApiKey,
    authDomain: StaticConfig.firebaseAuthDomain,
    projectId: StaticConfig.firebaseProjectId,
    storageBucket: StaticConfig.firebaseStorageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: StaticConfig.firebaseMessagingSenderId,
    appId: StaticConfig.firebaseAppId
  })
);
```

We Call it:

```
const webRemoteConfig = registerRemoteConfig(webFirebaseApp);

 useEffect(() => {
    setRemoteConfigValues((currentValues) => ({...currentValues, IsLoading: true, HasError: undefined}));
    Promise.all<IncompleteRemoteConfigValues>([
      fetchRemoteConfig(webRemoteConfig),
      fetchDotEnvFeatureFlagOverrides(!isDevelopmentMode),
      fetchRemoteConfig(mobileRemoteConfig),
      fetchDotEnvFeatureFlagOverrides(isDevelopmentMode)
    ]).then((values) => {
      setRemoteConfigValues({
        ...RemoteConfigDefaults,
        ...values.reduce<IncompleteRemoteConfigValues>(
          (mergedRemoteValues, remoteValues) => ({...mergedRemoteValues, ...remoteValues}),
          {}
        ),
        IsLoading: false
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

any insight into what maybe causing this would be a great help.